# genetic algorithm handling negative fitness values

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement genetic algorithm for maximizing a function of n variables. However the problem is that the fitness values can be negative and I am not sure about how to handle negative values while doing selection. I read this article [Linear fitness scaling in Genetic Algorithm produces negative fitness values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660069/linear-fitness-scaling-in-genetic-algorithm-produces-negative-fitness-values) 
but it's not clear to me how the negative fitness values were taken care of and how scaling factors a and b were calculated.

Also, from the article I know that roulette wheel selection only works for positive fitness value. Is it the same for tournament selection as well ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tournament selection is not affected by this problem. It simply compares the fitness values of a uniformly sampled subset of size n of the population and takes the one with the best value. Still of course this means that, if you sample without repetition then the worst n-1 individuals will never get selected. If you sample with repetition they have a chance of being selected.

As with proportional selection: It doesn't work with negative fitness values. You can only apply "windowing" or "scaling" of your fitness values in which case they work again.

I once programmed some [sampling methods](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/browser/trunk/sources/HeuristicLab.Random/3.3/RandomEnumerable.cs) as extension methods for C#'s IEnumerable among them is a SampleProportional and SampleProportionalWithoutRepetition extension method. They're part of HeuristicLab under GPL license.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am wondering whether repetition can cause problems. Here repetition seems to be a good choice but is there any reason of not going for it.

Comment: Well you do have to use repetitions, because you need to select some solutions multiple times as you need 2 * population size for your parents. You could select each pair without repetition, but in general that's not really worth caring about. Except if you have small population sizes. But if they go into the hundreds the chance of a solution mating with itself is pretty slim.

Answer (score 10):

When you have negative values, you could try to find the smallest fitness value in your population and add its opposite to every value. This way you will no longer have negative values, while the differences between fitness values will remain the same.

Comment: Correct: In effect you normalise the values to a positive range.

Comment: And if apply this even when there are no negative values, it wouldn't be problem, right ? I am just thinking of avoiding a check for negative values.

Comment: @vjain27 As far as i know, it shouldn't be a problem. The roulette wheel selection already takes into account the average fitness in the population, so selection shouldn't be affected.

Comment: No your normalization is not the same. If you just shift it upwards so that every value is positive the smallest fitness value becomes 0 and thus has absolutely no chance of being selected, while before it might have had a chance. I'm not saying that there is another way however, just that it's not the same.

Comment: I had a similar problem these days and i have solved it by increasing the fitness just enough so that the smallest value had a value bigger (not equal) to 0, giving it a chance to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it's late to answer, but still someone could google it.

First of all - yes, you can use negative fitness. But I'm totally suggest you not to do it, because I've did it and experienced a lot of problems (still doable, but totally not recommended). So here's explanation:

Say you have population of N creatures. After simulation they all have some fitness values f(n), where f(n) is fitness and n is creature number. After this you want to build some probability distribution to determine which creatures should be killed (of course you can delete say 40% of just worst creatures but it would be better if you use distribution). How do you build such distribution? Say f(a) = 50, and f(b) = 100, so creature b is 2 times better than creature a, so probably you want to make the 
survival probability of creature a 2 times higher than creature b (makes great sense if your fitness value is linear). In case you wonder how to do it:

Let's say that sum( f (n) ) is the summ of all fitness values. Then 
survival probability p(a) of creature a is:

p(a) = f(a) / sum( f(n) )

This will do the trick.

But now let's make negative fitness allowed. Say f(a) = 50, f(b) = 100, f(c) = -1000. b is again 2 times better than a, makes sense, but it's -10 times better than c? Doesn't make sense. Gentleman above suggested you to add oppositive of worst fitness value, which kinda can "fix" your situation, but really it don't (I maked same mistake before). Okay, let's add 1000 to all fitness values:

f(a) = 1050, f(b) = 1100, f(c) = 0, so survival  probability of c is zero now, okay, we can take it. But let's compare a and b now:

b is 1.05 better than a now, which means that fitness of a and b is almost the same, which is totally unacceptable, because it **clearly** was 2 times better than a (of course in assumption that fitness is linear, but this will mess up nonlinear fitnesses as well)! You can't escape this problem, it will constantly get in your way, because probability can't be negative, so you either can remove the probability from evolution (which is not very good thing to do) or you can do some exceptions and tricks.

Since it was too late in my scenario to remove negative fitness, here's my way in order to fix things up:

Once again, you have population of N creatures. Say neg(N) gives you all negative fitness creatures and pos(N) positive fitness creatures (it's your call to make zero negative or positive, doesn't matter in this case). And let's say you need D creatures to die. And now here's the trick:

the higher f( c ) ( c is pos creature) value, the better creature is, so we can use its fitness to determine the probability of survivial. But the lower (bigger negative) f( m ) (m is neg creature ), the worser creature is, so we can use its fitness to determine the probability of dying.

Now, if D > neg(N) then all neg(N) will die, and (D-neg(N))  of pos(N) will die with use of probability distribution based on all positive creatures fitness (probability of survival p(a) = f(a) / sum( pos(n) ) ). But if D < neg(N), then all pos(N) will survive, and D of neg(N) creatures will die with use of probability distribution based on all negative creatures fitness (probability of **dying** p(a) = f(a) / sum( neg(n) ) (f(a) will be negative, but sum( neg(n) ) will be negative as well, so probability will be positive).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main issue people are running into here is that they're treating the fitness score improperly. Let's think about an example fitness score as the temperature inside of a truck shipping frozen goods. The truck's internal temperature should be -2 C... but that's also 28.4 F. They are the same exact fitness relative to the food staying frozen, but 2 * -2 = -4, and 2 * 28.4 is 56.8. "Two times colder" doesn't really make any sense here (-4 C != 14.2 F either). Same with fitness scores.

In the case of -1000 in [Volot's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433915/3501461), the difference between 50 and 100 is actually comparatively low: the important thing is that you'd pick either / both of those over the -1000, which you will definitely do if you just subtract -1000 from everything. Then the next generation of children may have fitness scores of 50, 100, 200, and 10, let's say. Now the difference between 50 and 100 is much more pronounced, and 50 will have a much lower chance of getting picked. Remember genetic algorithms are iterative. It also reminds me of a saying: You don’t have to run faster than the bear to get away. You just have to run faster than the guy next to you. 50 just needs to outrun -1000 to survive to reproduce.

The problem of subtracting the min resulting in 0 also can be avoided. When estimating probability distributions, people will add 1 occurrence to every (known) possible outcome so that extremely rare events are still captured. That gets somewhat trickier with fitness scores. You can't just add 1. What if your fitness scores are 0.01, 0.02, and -0.01? 1.03, 1.02, and 1.00 are going to result in picking a low relative fitness a lot. You can instead add the lowest non-zero value to everything, resulting in 0.04, 0.05, and 0.02. For the -1000 case, it results in 2150, 2100, and 1050 (so everything that used to be 0 will always be half as likely as the next lowest fitness to get picked)

Still, to make things as consistent as possible with what is a more typical GA sampling method, I would only subtract the min and add back in a small amount of fitness when there are negative values. When everything is positive, there's no reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been here for a long time, but if new guys want to know the best way to deal with negative values, and also your problem is minimum. Here is the code for it.

```
from numpy import min, sum, ptp, array 
from numpy.random import uniform 

list_fitness1 = array([-12, -45, 0, 72.1, -32.3])
list_fitness2 = array([0.5, 6.32, 988.2, 1.23])

def get_index_roulette_wheel_selection(list_fitness=None):
    """ It can handle negative also. Make sure your list fitness is 1D-numpy array"""
    scaled_fitness = (list_fitness - min(list_fitness)) / ptp(list_fitness)
    minimized_fitness = 1.0 - scaled_fitness
    total_sum = sum(minimized_fitness)
    r = uniform(low=0, high=total_sum)
    for idx, f in enumerate(minimized_fitness):
        r = r + f
        if r > total_sum:
            return idx

get_index_roulette_wheel_selection(list_fitness1)
get_index_roulette_wheel_selection(list_fitness2)
```

1. Make sure your fitness list is 1D-numpy array
2. Scaled the fitness list to the range [0, 1]
3. Transform maximum problem to minimum problem by 1.0 - scaled_fitness_list
4. Random a number between 0 and sum(minimizzed_fitness_list)
5. Keep adding element in minimized fitness list until we get the value greater than the total sum
6. You can see if the fitness is small --> it has bigger value in minimized_fitness --> It has a bigger chance to add and make the value greater than the total sum.